# error message java: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, appium

I am using the IntelliJ IDEA to edit my java, I want to using appium to launch the app on iOS simulator, but return java:  expected. Here is my code below, may I know where is the wrong? thanks

```
package.iosautomationpackage;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Example1InstallAppOnSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "16.2");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone SE (3rd generation)");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/raymond/Downloads/LearnAutoQA_01/ios-uicatalog-master/UIKitCatalog/UIKitCatalog/UIKitCatalog.entitlements");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(url, dc);
    }
}
```

I want to run the code without this error, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue about appium, but you have a syntax error in your Java code:

```
package.iosautomationpackage;
```

should be:

```
package iosautomationpackage;
```

(space between package and the packagename instead of a dot).

Also make sure the package name is correct.

Comment: thank you sir, I think this syntax error is the key, and actually I am also new in Java too